# Display 0 or NULL values in output query from a system table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to research this question, and the answers I find all revolve around using outer joins to solve it.  I am only using a single table for this.  The real problem comes because my resulting query, I would like to use in an SP to run through every database on the server.
The base query looks like this:

```
SELECT name

FROM sys.database_principals

WHERE type in ('U','G')

AND name LIKE '%$'
```

Easy enough. If there is a user, the user is returned xyz\user1$.  If there is no user, the line is just blank.  I would like to list the database, user/group/NULL as applicable, and a count of the returns.

I worked my way up to this query:

```
SELECT DB_NAME () as _Database, name, count (name) as _Count

FROM sys.database_principals

WHERE type in ('U','G')

AND name LIKE '%$'

group by name
```

This query has the exact same output as the first (blank output with only column headers for no returns).  I have even attempted to do the left join method by trying to join on sys.databases. I have attempted CASE, IFNULL, COALESCE, but I might just misunderstand the finer points. Here is the stored procedure and one of my more flawed attempts to get this to work, but shows at least a middle step of where my head is attempting to go:

```
Declare @command varchar(1000)

Select @command =

'USE ?

SELECT ''?'' as _Database, p.name, count (p.name) as _Count

FROM sys.database_principals p

left join sys.databases d

on DB_NAME () = d.name

WHERE p.type in (''U'',''G'')

AND p.name LIKE ''%$''

group by p.name'

select @@SERVERNAME as 'Host Name'

exec sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably another way you could tackle this but using your query as a starting point I added a temp table for the database names. Then used sp_MSforeachdb to update the temp table. Be wary though...that is an undocumented system procedure and it has some flaws. The worst being that sometimes it will decide to skip a database and nobody seems to really know why. You can read more about the problems with that procedure and a better alternative here. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/

```
create table #DatabaseNames
(
    DBName sysname
    , PrincipalCount int
)

insert #DatabaseNames
(
    DBName
    , PrincipalCount
)
select name
    , 0 --want to default our count to 0
from sys.databases

declare @command nvarchar(max) = 
'update #DatabaseNames 
set PrincipalCount = 
(
    select count (p.name)
    FROM sys.database_principals p 
    where p.type in (''U'', ''G'')  
        and name LIKE ''%$''
)
where DBName = DB_NAME()
'

exec sp_MSforeachdb @command

select * from #DatabaseNames

drop table #DatabaseNames
```

Comment: This solution gets closer to the formatting.  However, it is returning 0 for all the PrincipalCount even on the dbs I know have users in 'U', 'G' and like '%$'.  Also, I need to display said user names for the databases that do have returns. Presumably I would just add and extra column 'Name' in the create table and insert statements?

Comment: If you are wanting the user names then using count is rather pointless. It will always be 1 or NULL.

Comment: The reason I was wanting the count is for the databases that have no users/groups to display there are none.  This is for auditing purposes on accounts.  I am not married to the way i was trying to do it.  If there is a better way, I am open to it. In the end, I need to show Database, User/Group Accounts.  I really can do without the Count as long as the database shows up in the list and no name next to it can imply the 0 returns.